# Out-of-order and ignored lines of code in onRequestPermissionsResult()?

Tags: android

I have a dialog that asks the user if they want to allow or deny the permission for the app to access the phone's file system. Upon denial, nothing happens, which is the intended functionality. But upon allowance, it seems that some lines of code aren't being executed.

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        Log.i("DESIRED ACTION", String.valueOf(DESIRED_ACTION) + " " + String.valueOf(DESIRED_ACTION == ACTION_ADD_ENTRY));
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.i("Testing", String.valueOf(DESIRED_ACTION == ACTION_ADD_ENTRY));
                    if (DESIRED_ACTION == ACTION_ADD_ENTRY) {
                        Log.i("Testing", "Testing");
                        addEntry();
                    }
                    if (DESIRED_ACTION == ACTION_ADD_ENTRY) {
                        Log.i("Permissions", "Writing granted");
                    }
                }
                // else if not permission granted
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addEntry() {
        Log.i("Invocation", "ADD ENTRY");
    }
```

The relevant portion of the log with the info filter shows only the following:

```
.../DESIRED ACTION: 1 true
.../Permissions: Writing granted
```

In the log, `Permissions: Writing granted` was displayed, meaning that `DESIRED_ACTION == ACTION_ADD_ENTRY`. But if that's the case, shouldn't the lines of code inside the if statement before it also have run, causing `Testing: Testing` and `Invocation: ADD ENTRY` to also appear in the log?

I don't understand what is going on here. Why is some of the code being omitted?

Comment: That is strange. Since its the same condition. But why have two separate `if` statements in the block when they just have the same condition?

Comment: @McAwesomville I've since collapsed them under the same `if` statement to see if that did anything, but still only the same two entries appear on the log.

Comment: It seems you have filtered out some logs based on the filter and may be that's why you are not able to see the other logs.Please post the exact logs as shown in logcat.

Comment: What @ShadabAnsari said is highly possible. You might be filtering the logs for a specific text.